# Is it possible to pass null property's value in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin, system-properties

I have a property which is designed like `-dVerbose` in `mvn dependency:tree` plugin. It does not require any value. If it is specified then some additional work is done in my application's tests.

So in Maven failsafe plugin i would like to either set some value (does not matter which one, but **not null**) or set it to **null** depending on which Maven profile is active.

I tried something like this:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <doNotInsertData>${null}</doNotInsertData>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

or `<doNotInsertData>null</doNotInsertData>` or `<doNotInsertData/>`.

But unfortunately all of above leads to not null property value when i run maven goal. Is it possible at all to pass null-value with *pom.xml*?

Comment: The verbose property in `mvn dependency:tree` is a boolean. `-Dverbose` and `-Dverbose=true` are synonyms. To set 'null', use `-Dverbose=false`. Can't you do the same with your property?

Comment: Use `Boolean` and don't put tags in pom.xml.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens yeah, i would like to do the same, but `Boolean.getBoolean("verbose")` would return `false` if you just mention the property with `-Dverbose` while Maven treats it as `true`. How? I tried to analyse it's source code and discovered that Maven has `@Parameter` annotation but unfortunately did not find where it is processed.